How to make bunny hop in ursina engine?
I want to make bhop mechanics in ursina engine. if the spacebar is pressed, the character will jump forever, and if the w button is pressed, the speed will increase with each jump. it is also desirable (but not necessary) to make a speed up on strafe.

What have you tried so far?

So by 'bunny hopping' I assume you mean that the character moves faster than when running/sprinting, with the speed increasing each jump.
The speed can either be applied during jumping or during ground movement (or both). In my experience, being in a jump-state forever could cause problems in the end but lets say we do just that. You'd have something like:
def input(self, key):
    if (key == 'space') 
        self.position += self.forward * player.speed
        self.position_y += jump_upwards_speed 

In the example above, depending on if you want to move faster during the jump or when on ground, the player.speed value will either be a set speed or multiplied with the current speed boost.
For the actual bunny hopping, you multiply the current speed for each jump you do.
Remember that you only want to add to the multiplier if you start a jump from grounded.
current_speed_multiplier = current_speed_multiplier + per_hop_multiplier_amount
# then update the player speed 
player.speed = original_speed * current_speed_multiplier

Be aware that if you don't add a maximum amount of times you can speed up or a maximum height you can reach with the jump, this could cause a few issues.
Since you don't want to keep the speed multiplier forever, you also need to diminish the speed on each update (or on a set timer).
current_speed_multiplier = current_speed_multiplier - diminish_value_per_update

To summarize:

Move the player character up during jumping if a button is held, and down if not
Determine when the character is on ground again
Apply a multiplier each time the character jumps from ground
Apply the speed multiplier during jumping and/or running
Decrease the speed if standing still (or on a timer)

But this will depend on the implementation of the rest of your code, I suggest trying yourself and see how it works!
